# How can I remove these bolts that connect my safe to the wall?

Tags: drywall, safety, screws, structural, bolts

So in my room I have this safe I want to remove it because it's in an inconvenient spot and rather have it in another room. I have these bolts inside of the safe that are in my wall and the problem is, I can't get it out. There is nothing I can do to remove it and I don't know if there is anything else on the other side of the wall that could damage the wall when I remove it. Anybody got tips or answers on how I can remove it?

[image]

Comment: Is the picture of the inside safe wall?  Why can't you remove the nut and pull the safe off the bolt?

Comment: "There is nothing I can do to remove it" Can you explain what you tried and why it didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

After adjusting the exposure on your picture, I suggest you buy a wrench, if "there's nothing you can do to remove it" (and you actually own it, as opposed to it being part of a rented/leased property. *Which "my room" as opposed to "my house" calls into question...*)

[image: Exposeure adjusted]

Comment: I thought it was just a simple lock nut at first, but zooming in there seems to be a separate lock ring(?) on the nut.  Might just be my eyes.

Comment: It's a terrible picture. We'd need a better picture to have any idea if it's more complicated than "lefty loosey" which is what it looks like to me from what I can actually see in that terrible picture. Could just be a nylock nut, and these do lefty loosey just fine..

Comment: Guess a simple wrench would be okay, but a cutting torch or angle grinder is more fun.

Comment: @crip659 Fine, let's use the oxygen lance on it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_lance Pretty sure a sledgehammer will do the job, too. Ah, ya know what, it's a safe. Let's do it the old school traditional way with nitroglycerin.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the bolts are only into one plane (wall or floor) you would open the safe, unscrew the nuts, remove the safe from the wall, then deal with the bolts or "studs". The latter would be screwed into the wall and you would unscrew them with a pipe wrench or with pliers.

There is probably a section of the stud next to the wall where there are no threads or the threads are not used. The best pliers would be locking pliers like Vise-Grips. Maybe channel locks would work.

If the studs would be special design with have wrenching flats exposed when the safe was removed, then a regular wrench could be used.

Comment: You could use a die grinder with the appropriate blade and cut it off.